# Что делать с полем у которого название @timestamp?

Tags: vue.js, elasticsearch, timestamp

Получаю из эластика в VueJS логи и в общем все норм, но timestamp почему-то приходит с символом @ вначале.

```
{
  "Host": "...",
  "@timestamp": "2019-04-29T12:31:51.825396547Z",
  "Message": "...",
  "Data": {...},
  "Level": "..."
}
```

В итоге получаю *Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@'*. 
Наверно глупый вопрос, но что за формат такой и как его вывести?

Comment: видимо вам приходит такой джейсон, это поле вы можете сохранить как дату)

Comment: То, что это json понятно) Проблема в том, что когда я пытаюсь обратиться к этому полю, я получаю ошибку.

Comment: Во Vuejs нельзя называть данные, начиная с подчеркивания. Похоже с `@` тоже